# how to solve this error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Tags: php, pdo

I create a shopping cart using OOP PHP.When I return a single product information data from database through HTML form to perform edit operation, 
I face this type of error

"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineShop\src\Product.php:100 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineShop\src\Product.php(100): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM t...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineShop\views\Product\editProduct.php(18): App\Product->view() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineShop\src\Product.php on line 100"

My editProduct file code below that

```
<?php
  require_once("../../vendor/autoload.php");
  use App\Product;

  $product  = new Product();
  $product->setData($_GET);
  $allData = $product->view();



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Book Title Create Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" align="center" id="body">
    <h3>Add Product Information</h3>
</div>
<div align="center" class="container">

    <form action="store.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <td><label class="control-label"> Product Name:</label></td>
                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productName" value=""<?php echo $allData->productName;?>""></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label class="control-label">Category :</label></td>
                <td><select name="categoryID" class="form-control">
                        <?php
                        $category = new App\Category();
                        $oneData= $category->index();
                        foreach($oneData as $singleData){

                            ?>
                            <option
                                <?php if($allData->categoryID==$singleData->categoryID){?>
                                      selected ="selected"
                           <?php } ?>
                                value="<?php echo $singleData->categoryID; ?>"><?php echo $singleData->categoryName;?></option>
                        <?php }?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label class="control-label">Brand :</label> </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="brandID" class="form-control">
                        <?php
                        $brand = new App\Brand();
                        $allData= $brand->index();
                        foreach($allData as $singleData){
                            ?>
                            <option
                                <?php if($allData->brandID==$singleData->brandID){?>
                                    selected ="selected"
                                <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $singleData->brandID;?>"><?php echo $singleData->brandName;?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="control-label">Description:</label></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="description" value="<?php echo $allData->description;?>" class="form-control" ></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="control-label">Price:</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $allData->price;?>" id="price" name="price" class="form-control">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="control-label">Upload Image :</label> </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="input-group" type="file"  value="<?php echo $allData->image;?>" id="image" name="image" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="control-label">Product Type :</label></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="productType">
                        <option value="0">Featured</option>
                        <option value="1">General</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>

</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="submit" value="EDIT" class="btn btn-success">
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
de here
```

My view method below like that which is used for viewing single product information to perform edit operation.

```
                public function view()
            {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE productID=".$this->productID;
                $STH = $this->DBH->query($sql);
                $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                return $STH->fetch();
            }
```

Pls  help me to provide solution this type of error.

Comment: Please, format your question better. Quote your errors so they are shown inside the proper box. Check for indentation. HTML indentation is pretty well, but can be optimized. The second block indentation is a bit weird, but is small so is not that bad. Btw, proper indentation is a must for someone understand your question better.

Comment: Also, if it says that the error is in a SQL query at line 100 of file `C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineShop\src\Product.php`, you must `echo` the query and show it here and also show where is the line 100 of that file, so we know how the query looks like and how are you creating it. Is difficult to know what query is trying to do without viewing the query. And finally, maybe doing that you see the problem and don't need to ask a question here.

Comment: [As you can read here (must read for you)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), pretend that you are talking to a busy colleage, so always try to minimize the code and point out each problem if you want to get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that $this->productID is not coming as empty

update your function code like below and see:

```
public function view()
{

    if(!empty($this->productID)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE productID=".$this->productID;
        $STH = $this->DBH->query($sql);
        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $STH->fetch();       
    }
        return [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if productID is an iteger type

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_product` WHERE `produt_id`= ".$this->productID;
```

if productID is an VARCHAR OR TEXT type:-

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_product` WHERE `product_id` ="'.$this->productID.'"';
```